# How to kill shell script without killing currently executed line

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am running a shell script, something like `sh script.sh` in bash. The script contains many lines, some of which take seconds and others take days to execute. How can I kill the `sh` command but not kill its command currently running (the current line from the script)?

Comment: I believe you cannot. However, you might have coded your script cleverly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have your script running for days and then you don't just want to kill it without knowing if one of its children finished.

Find the pid of your process, using `ps`.

Then

```
child=$(pgrep -P $pid)
while kill -s 0 $child
do
    sleep 1
done
kill $pid
```

Comment: Yes - this is exactly what I needed.  Thank you so much!

Comment: There's a massive window of opportunity here for the parent process to spawn another child process in between testing for any children and killing the parent.

Comment: yes, and when the new child is created the while loop exists and the parent is killed, which is understood as the intention

Answer (score 2):

You haven't specified exactly what should happen when you 'kill' your script., but I'm assuming that you'd like the currently executing line to complete and then exit before doing any more work.

This is probably best achieved only by coding your script to behave in such a way as to receive such a kill command and respond in an appropriate way - I don't think that there is any magic to do this in linux.

for example:

- You could trap a signal and then set a variable
- Check for existence of a file (e.g `touch /var/tmp/trigger`)

Then after each line in your script, you'd need to check to see if each the trap had been called (or your trigger file created) - and then exit. If the trigger has not been set, then you continue on and do the next piece of work.

To the best of my knowledge, you can't trap a `SIGKILL` (-9) - if someone sends that to your process, then it will die.

HTH, Ace

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can think of achieving this is for the parent process to trap the kill signal, set a flag, and then repeatedly check for this flag before executing another command in your script.

However the subprocesses need to also be immune to the kill signal.  However bash seems to behave different to ksh in this manner and the below seems to work fine.

```
#!/bin/bash

QUIT=0

trap "QUIT=1;echo 'term'" TERM

function terminated {
  if ((QUIT==1))
  then
    echo "Terminated"
    exit
  fi
}

function subprocess {
  typeset -i N
  while ((N++<3))
  do
    echo $N
    sleep 1
  done
}

while true
do
  subprocess
  terminated
  sleep 3
done
```